# How do I query Quickbooks using the API for EntityRef = '{-199}'

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to retrieve records from QB using the following query:

```
`$purchases = $PurchaseService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Purchase where EntityRef = '{-199}' STARTPOSITION 0 MAXRESULTS 20");
```

foreach ($purchases as $purchase)
{
     print_r($purchase);
}`

I'm getting this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/xxx/qbapp/accounts_payable.php on line 50

But when I run this query without the WHERE clause it runs without an issue.

```
$purchases = $PurchaseService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Purchase STARTPOSITION 0 MAXRESULTS 20");
```

Part of the output array shows the 'EntityRef' - Can someone please help and explain why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Post the raw response you're sending to Intuit, and the raw response you're getting back. e.g.: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/debugging.php#L38

Comment: Thanks for your reply Keith,  I'm very new to using the API and wanted clarification as to if I am using the correct query syntax?  Is there a list anywhere in the project to expand on this query?  Some examples other than the basic select statement with no 'where' clause?  quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_purchase_query.php  "$purchases = $PurchaseService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Purchase where (some expression needed here) ");"

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/20_explore_the_quickbooks_online_api/50_data_queries     I can't tell if it's correct or not -- you need to post the raw request and raw response as I indicated in order for me to be able to tell you if it's valid or not.